Send email from sheet based on a response
I would like to send an email to the respondent (Column C) when book is "Approved" or "Not Approved" from the drop down in Column 1 on the "Anchor", "Book Club", and "Classroom Library" tabs.
I've tried a few scripts, but I'm having problems figuring it out. I'd like the email to state the status of the request (Approved, or Not Approved) and give follow up instructions. If it's approved, there's an order form to fill out (google doc), so I would add link. If it's not approved, I'd like them to know to contact the Director of Student Improvement. Any help is appreciated. Here is the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nGVatm_I5vqRSad1ZWKLyO1jKnaCCT3zvUWjIPWdKAo/edit?gid=495720352#gid=495720352
I tried an If statement, but I couldn't find a formula that included email. I tried researching how to script it, but couldn't find what I needed.
I was expecting to receive an email when the drop down was selected.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. While a link to a spreadsheet might be helpful, questions on this site should be self-contained. This implies that all the relevant details, such as some sample input data and a [mcve], should be included directly in the question body.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! An answer has been posted in response to your question. Please review the answer if it correctly solves your issue. If it does, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and/or upvote the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that their issue can be resolved. For further details, you may read the article on how to accept the answer.

Using Appscript to send emails based on edits
Problem Statement: Automatically send an email to the respondent listed in Column C when the status in Column A (Approval Notes) is changed to :
"Approved - Complete Order (link above)" or
"Not approved - contact DSI"
Note: Changes are made on different sheets : Column A.
I have duplicated your sample sheet to better understand how to achieve automatic email sending and it works on my end.  Below is the App Script code I have written for your sheet:
 function checkAndSendEmail() {
  var sheets = ['Anchor', 'Book Club', 'Classroom Library'];
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  if (!sheets.includes(sheet.getName())) {
    return;
  }
  
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var statusColumn = 1; 
  var emailColumn = 3;
  var bookColumn;

  switch (sheet.getName()) {
    case 'Anchor':
      bookColumn = 14; 
      break;
    case 'Book Club':
    case 'Classroom Library':
      bookColumn = 9; 
      break;
    default:
      return;
  }
  
  var status = range.getValue();

  if (range.getColumn() === statusColumn) {
    var emailAddress = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), emailColumn).getValue();
    var bookName = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), bookColumn).getValue();

    if (status === "Approved - Complete Order (link above)") {
      sendApprovalEmail(emailAddress, bookName);
    } else if (status === "Not approved - contact DSI") {
      sendRejectionEmail(emailAddress, bookName);
    }
  }
}

function sendApprovalEmail(emailAddress, bookName) {
  var subject = "Your Request has been Approved";
  var body = `Congratulations! Your request for the book "${bookName}" has been approved. Please fill out the order form using the following link: . If you have any questions, feel free to contact us.`;
  
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, body, {
    htmlBody: body
  });
}

function sendRejectionEmail(emailAddress, bookName) {
  var subject = "Your Request has not been Approved";
  var body = `We regret to inform you that your request for the book "${bookName}" has not been approved. Please contact the Director of Student Improvement for further assistance.`;
  
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, body, {
    htmlBody: body
  });
}

Note: On line 29, add your form link.

Set a Trigger:
1.) Click on triggers (Clock icon on the left side of your screen)
2.) Click "Add Triggers"
3.) Follow this configuration: Trigger Configurations

References:
Manage triggers manually
sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)
JavaScript Switch Statement

Wow.... you are amazing. I changed my share settings to edit in this file and copied your script into it: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nGVatm_I5vqRSad1ZWKLyO1jKnaCCT3zvUWjIPWdKAo/edit?usp=sharing    I'm hoping we can add on: #1--Is there a way to add the "Title of Book" column to the email response? In the Anchor tab it's in column N. On the other two tabs it's in Column I. It would be great if an email was sent for the other two options in the drop down..I'm waiting for my boss to get to me about wording, but I can always change it. Thank you, again.... simply amazing.

@BethVarsho The code above has been modified to include the title of the book in the email. Please check if it works correctly for the three sheets.

It works! Thank you so much. I will try to duplicate what you have for the other two dropdown options. You are truly great. Thanks again for all your help!

I was able to use what you had and add script for the other two drop downs. Thank you so much for all of your work!!

Welcome to Stackoverflow. If an answer works well with the question posted. We recommend accepting or upvoting the answer this way the community will have a chance to look at the same answer facing the same question as you have.

My boss has tasked me to keep adding to the script for all the other tabs. I used what I had and I'm soooooo close! There is just one tiny glitch that I can't figure out and it's on line 27 of the script. The response is supposed to pull from column P of the "Inst Program" tab which I believe equates to # 16, but it's pulling from column I. I tried changing the number, but it always pulls from column I. Link to file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_VyYcgdFEMbf2FoCBmHth2-j_rfRFnCkCD00GAOVUCs/edit?gid=243408910#gid=243408910
